# How can I get list of tables in a table collection?

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009

I need to do a work about virtual companies. So I'm struggling with table collections. Is there a way to get a list of tables in a table collection?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the names of the tables in a table collection using [SysDictTableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sysdicttablecollection.aspx) like this :

```
    SysDictTableCollection  tableCollection;
    TableName               tableName;
    ;

    //replace Batch with your table collection name
    tableCollection = new SysDictTableCollection("Batch"); 
    tableName       = tableCollection.nextTable();

    while (tableName)
    {
        info(tableName);
        tableName = tableCollection.nextTable();
    }
```